# How to create command shortcut to .sh file?

Tags: linux, symlink

I want to type `firefox` in terminal and run Mozilla browser.

So  I try to create  sym-link:
`ln -s /opt/firefox firefox`

but after typing `firefox` in terminal I get an error: `bash: firefox: command not found`

Where is problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You created a link to `/opt/firefox` (is this really the firefox binary, can you start FF when calling `/opt/firefox`?) in the directory that was your current working directory when you issued the command, likely your home directory.

However,  the directory where your link was created is not in your `$PATH`, so you still can't run it directly.

The solution is to either create the link into a directory with is in your path. E.g.:

```
ln -s /opt/firefox /usr/local/bin/firefox
```

or add `/opt` to your path, but I would recommend the first option.

A remark: `/opt/` is a strange place to put a binary in. How did you install Firefox anyway and why didn't you use your distributions package management system?

Comment: I downloaded `tar.bz2` file of Firefox and unarchived it to `/opt/`. Hmm, where is place to put binary files in linux?  

P.S. Sym-lin (i.e. `ln -s` command) add information to $PATH environment variable?

Comment: As I said, you ususally install software with the tools your distribution offers. Try `apt-get install firefox` (Debian, Ubuntu) or `yum install firefox` (Redhat, Centos, Fedora, Suse). If you downloaded and untarred the file in `/opt/`, it will likely have created a subdirectoy `/opt/firefox` and the binary to start` is `/opt/firefox/firefox`. The link to create would be `ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/local/bin/firefox`.

Comment: You can search serverfault or google to learn how to add stuff to your `$PATH`.

Comment: yes, I tried `/opt/firefox/firefox` - it too don't help, but  `ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/local/bin/firefox` helped! thanks. `export PATH=$PATH:/new/path` (as answered `binfalse`) exist only within terminal session, but after executing your command reference to `firefox` persisted in system..But can you explain why you mapped firefox.sh to **local/bin/firefox**? Why **local/bin/firefox**?

Comment: Simple. `/usr/local/bin` is usually in the default `$PATH` as defined by the OS and I like to put nonstandard binaries in there, as this was the tradtional location for *local* installs.

Comment: Is better to copy whole `firefox` directory into `/usr/local/bin/` or better no copy only containment of directory (i.e. binary files)?

Comment: it is better to use your distribution's package management tools to install the pre-packaged version of firefox (aka iceweasel).

Answer (score 2):

First of all please make sure, that `/opt/firefox` is the executable and not a director. Try to execute `/opt/firefox`, if that works you can add the directory with the executable to your `$PATH` variable.

### Supp

If you try to execute a command `cmd`, your system scans all path elements in this variable for an executable with the name `cmd`. If you want to extend the directories to scan just update the variable like:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/new/path
```

So the next time you try to run `cmd` your systems also looks for the executable in `/new/path`. That means, if your firefox executable is located in `/opt` just add the following to your `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt
```

Comment: yes. you right. helped. But I use CentOs, and I know if I execute `export` command so "exported" variable will exist only within terminal session, after closing terminal all variables added using `export` will be removed - this rules also may be applied in our case (i.e. extending `$PATH` variable)? Or this change will be saved (even after reboot) because we only extend (not create) $PATH?

Comment: @MyTitle: If you add the line to your ~/.bashrc file, it will be permanent (if you use the bash, of course).

Answer (score 1):

The default firefox executable when Firefox is installed usually resides in /usr/lib/firefox- which is a directory:

Please try to verify this on your system with the command:

```
ls /usr/lib/firefox*
```

which on my system yields the result:

```
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 1020 2012-09-12 06:29 /usr/lib/firefox-3.6.28
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root  916 2011-04-25 18:56 /usr/lib/firefox-4.0
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root   80 2011-04-25 18:56 /usr/lib/firefox-addons
```

The Firefox icon at the top of a Linux main bar (top of monitor screen) is connected to the Firefox executable via a symbolic link in /usr/bin such as:

```
ls -lt firefox*

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 2012-09-12 06:29 firefox -> firefox-3.6.28
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 2012-09-12 06:29 firefox-3.6.28 -> ../lib/firefox-3.6.28/firefox
```

With this structure, you can have multiple versions of Firefox symbolically linked, and to try a different version you would simply remove the firefox link in /usr/bin, and then create a new firefox to a different version in /usr/lib, such as (where the # prompt below is the root account prompt:

```
# rm firefox
# ln -s ../lib/firefox-4.0/firefox.sh firefox
```

As mentioned in previous posts on this topic, you need to make sure that the linked-to object actually exists when you create a symbolic link to it.